# Awesome WM restart flag

Tags: lua, startup, configuration-files, awesome-wm

Does awesome window manager set some kind of flag during restart. I've some autostart commands in `rc.lua` and they are executed every time I restart the window manager.

How can I determine in the `rc.lua` if the file execution is done because of a restart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, just want to comment @ploth 's answer...but not enough reputation.
The given code is the one on the former wiki, and it didn't work for me. I use this one :

```
function run_once(cmd)                 
 local findme = "ps x U $USER |grep '" .. cmd .. "' |wc -l"              
 awful.spawn.easy_async_with_shell( findme ,
   function(stdout,stderr,reason,exit_code) 
     if tonumber(stdout) <= 2 then
       awful.spawn( cmd )
     end
   end)
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Awesome v4.x?
Declare a `run_once` function.
*`numlockx on` as an example*

```
function run_once(cmd)                                                                                                               
  findme = cmd 
  firstspace = cmd:find(" ")
  if firstspace then
    findme = cmd:sub(0, firstspace-1)
  end        
  awful.spawn.with_shell("pgrep -u $USER -x " .. findme .. " > /dev/null || (" .. cmd .. ")")
end          

run_once("numlockx on")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the included `spawn.once` function, e.g.

```
awful.spawn.once("dex --autostart --environment awesome")
```

https://awesomewm.org/doc/api/libraries/awful.spawn.html#once